# Difference between #pragma omp master and checking if thread id equals to zero

Tags: multithreading, openmp

Is there a difference between storing each thread's id and checking if the thread id equals to zero or just putting your code in a `#pragma omp master`?

Apart from the fact that you waste time storing thread ids that you might not need in specific applications.

Also is there any chance that the thread with id equal to zero is not the master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenMP specification requires that the master thread's ID is 0.

Actual implementation differences aside, I would go for the #pragma construct for the two reasons that (a) it's more readable and the intension of the code is very obvious and (b) it allows the compiler to optimize better.

Comment: Is master thread mandatory to be run at least for one task? I mean is it possible that nothing runs on master and all tasks runs on other threads?